# Does Meteor and Iron Router's yield have an event hook? Template.yield.rendered?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I think this could be something that would be pretty useful.

If we had:

```
<template name="layout">

  {{> header }}

  {{> yield }}

  {{> footer }}

</template>
```

It would be nice to have something like

```
Template.yield.rendered = function() {
  // Do something after the yield has finished rendering
}
```

In addition to

```
Template.header.rendered = function() {
  // Do something after the header has finished rendering
}

Template.footer.rendered = function() {
  // Do something after the footer has finished rendering
}
```

Comment: You know that the rendered callback fires on the template being yielded, right? But you want to define a rendered callback being fired on all templates being yielded?

Comment: Yes. I want to define the rendered callback on `any` template that may be yielded. Say that I have common code that should be run after the `yield`. I don't want to write or reference that same code over and over again in each of the separate `.rendered` callbacks of each template.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to have the hook on 'any' template, you can define a nested yield template:

```
<template name="layout">

  {{> header }}

  {{> nested_yield }}

  {{> footer }}

</template>

<template name="nested_yield">
 {{> yield }}
</template>
```

then

```
Template.nested_yield.onRendered(function() {
  //your render code here
});
```

However you might run into issues with if the template ends up being updated with the same template as IronRouter caches templates and will not actually 're-render' a template.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot.